# How to fix Audit track issue in Open edX certificate

Tags: openedx

I have setup the certificate to following https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/named-release-cypress/configuration/enable_certificates.html URL.

When I try to generate the certificate then  I am getting the following error message.

```
Your enrollment: Audit track
You are enrolled in the audit track for this course. The audit track does not include a certificate.
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6EBt.png)

Comment: To enable the certificates, your course should be in "Honor mode"

Comment: Thanks @IsankaWijerathne, How to convert course "Honor mode".

Comment: LMS admin -> course modes then add a course mode for the particular course.

Comment: Already I have added the Mode: honor in LMS admin path - Home > Course Modes > Course modes > course-V1: xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Then you have to enroll students into that honor track.

Answer (score 0):

Upadate "mode" field in TABLE edxapp.student_courseenrollment